# Find the values of unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, constraints

I have an inequality of the kind $\dfrac{(1-a)}{b} > \dfrac{c+d}{c~ d}$ subject to the condition that $0 < c\leq 1, 0 < d \leq 1, a > 0 , b > 0 $.

How could I possibly find the values of $a, b, c, d$ that will satisfy the above condition ?

My attempts: $\dfrac{1-a}{b} \geq 2$. This leads to $2b + a < 1$. This can be solved to find the values of $a$ and $b$.  But $c$ and $d$ are not easy to evaluate.

Any suggestions to solve the same would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your post properly.  For example, it is not clear whether (c+d)/c*d means $\frac {c+d}{c\times d}$ or $\frac {c+d}{c}\times d$.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: Maybe you can isolate the $a$ in the left side of the equation, finding an upper bound for $a$ in terms of $b,c$ and $d$ and see where it can bring you

Comment: But I need a list of values of a, b, c and d and not just an upper bound.